# Python Linux Commands with Variables and Flags

Tags: python-3.x, linux

I have the following 2 lines of code in my Python script

```
echo_process = subprocess.run(['echo -e -n {okta_oauth2_client_id}:{okta_oauth2_client_secret}'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
base64_process = subprocess.run(['gbase64 -w 0'], input=echo_process.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
```

What I am doing here is echoing an id and secret and then piping the result to be base64'd.

However, I have a few problems.  When I print the result of the echo thus:

```
print(echo_process.stdout.decode())
```

I get the following output

```
-e -n {okta_oauth2_client_id}:{okta_oauth2_client_secret}
```

So, I have two issues here.  First, the flags, `-e` and `-n` are not treated as flags passed into the echo command but are instead echoed to the output.  Second, the variables are not expanded but instead treated like text that is printed to the output.

How do I resolve these issues?  I have tried a lot of things and nothing resolves this for me.

Comment: Can you try running `['echo', "-e", "-n" ... ]`

Comment: I get no output.

Comment: The {var} expansion only works in [formatted strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals) so to get that part to work you would need to put f before the quotes, eg `command=f'echo -e -n {okta_oauth2_client_id}:{okta_oauth2_client_secret}'`

Comment: As for the -e and -n echo options, is your system maybe running a simple version of the echo command which doesn't accept options and just echos everything? I tested your subprocess with the formatted strings and it worked for me in Python 3.9. Maybe add the full path to echo so you have: `echo_process = subprocess.run([f'/usr/bin/echo -e -n {okta_oauth2_client_id}:{okta_oauth2_client_secret}'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)`